# How can I handle return type for fetch async function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise, axios

I have a `fetchData` function like this:

```
export const fetchData = async (): Promise<IDataType[]> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get<IDataType>(url);
    return Object.values(data);
  } catch (error) {
    return error);
  }
};
```

VS Code shows an error. TypeScript doesn't allow to return unknown type for this function:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IDataType[]'.
```

I changed a line of code. It's working. However, I'm not sure whether it's the right way to do it or not:

```
export const fetchData = async (): Promise<IDataType[]> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get<IDataType>(url);
    return Object.values(data);
  } catch (error) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(`${error}`));
  }
};
```

As you can see, I added a `new Promise` keyword. Are there any best practices for it? I want to reach this function from components.

For example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    const fetchedData = await fetchData();
    ...
  };
```

Comment: Simpler: 1. `return Promise.reject(error)`; 2. `throw error` (because you're in an `async` function already); and 3. Just _don't catch it_ to start with.

Answer (score -2):

You can try casting the data to your type `IDataType[]` with [Type-Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

Edit: placed the type assertion in the correct place.

```js
    export const fetchData = async (): Promise<IDataType[]> => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(url);
        return Object.values(data) as IDataType[];
      } catch (error) {
        return error);
      }
    };
```